# How to remove a video from feed using Youtube API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Using the YouTube Data API v3, is there a way to remove a video from my feed?

Reading through the docs, I didn't see anything on the Video resource that  could match what I'm looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason you didn't find any is there's no support for this feature yet.